# Ionic 5: How to add event listener to ion-input using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am trying to add a event listener to a ion-input so then when there is a change and onkeyup the respective functions execute with the id passed in

Code

```
<ion-input id="totalTimeOpening" type="text"></ion-input>

<script>
    function testChange(id) {
        console.log(id + " Change");
    }

    function testOnKeyUp(id) {
        console.log(id + " KEYUP");
    }

    document.getElementById("totalTimeOpening").addEventListener('ionChange', testChange.bind('totalTimeOpening'), false);


    document.getElementById("totalTimeOpening").addEventListener('onkeyup', testOnKeyUp.bind('totalTimeOpening'), false);
</script>
```

The current code seems to pass the whole ion-input object in

Comment: On your testChange and testKeyUp when you log "id" what do you see, is there an attribute you want inside "id"?  Im unsure what it is you are looking for.

Comment: @KevinCrum Currently for testChange I see "[object CustomEvent] Change" and for testKeyUp I see nothing ie the lister is not working. What I want to see is the id of ion-input in there eg the output for testChange should be "totalTimeOpening Change" and and "totalTimeOpening KEYUP" for testOnKeyUp. Where that passed in id = totalTimeOpening

Comment: can you log id.value or id.target.value ?  forgive me i am away from my workstation to check my ionic code.

Comment: also, sometimes when your console says [object *] then you can json.stringify the object so you can see the data.  Its useful if you like using the console as a debugging tool: `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable))`

Comment: `<ion-input id="totalTimeOpening" type="text" (ionChange)="yourFunction()"></ion-input>` you can do it this way.

Comment: @KevinCrum, that does not work unfortunately

Comment: I basically want it to have the same behaviour as ,
<input type="text" id="totalTimeOpening"  onchange="testChange(this.id)">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.

```
    function testChange(id) {
        console.log(id + " Change");
    }

    function testOnKeyUp(id) {
        console.log(id + " KEYUP");
    }


        document.getElementById("totalTimeOpening").addEventListener('ionBlur', function(){
            testChange('totalTimeOpening')
        });


        document.getElementById("totalTimeOpening").addEventListener('ionInput', function(){
            testOnKeyUp('totalTimeOpening')
        });
```

the functions had to go inside function(){here}) and it works. Also the onkeyup won't work with ionic it seems and instead ionInput seems to work as a substitue